# Is there anyway to publish a web through script

Tags: google-apps-script

This is the scenario.
I have a script which I will copy to my clients folder.
My client does not have a clue about Google Drive. He wants me to do everything.

I simply want to copy the script to his drive and publish it as web app.
Is it possible programatically?

Also, will I face Authorization issues, if there is a way to do it.  Somebody must do the Authorization.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not. You can suggest it to Google as a feature request, but I doubt they'll do it. It seems to much of a "security" risk. People who write/use scripts are expected to understand how to do some of the basics like publish them and set authorization modes.